# MySQL complex query problem on a single table

Tags: mysql, select, nested

Having tried several possibilities I have come to a stop. Without overloading the mysql server with hundreds of queries, this is what I am trying to achieve:

Here is the table

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `refchid1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `refchid2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `refchid3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `refchid4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Explanation:

1. I am trying to adjust a person's status based on a complex tree. Each user has an id as denoted by the auto_increment id field.
2. User A has his details entered into the table.
3. User B is refered by User A, so when his details are entered refchid1 has the same id as User A.
4. User C is refered by User B, his refchid1 becomes the id of User B and his refchid2 becomes the id of User A.
5. User D is refered by User C, his refchid1 becomes that of User C, refchid2 that of UserB and refchid3 that of User A.

If you understand the referencing of the above, you are on the right track.

Sample Data of above description:

```
(6, 'Lars', 'Luna', 'Morbi.non.sapien@enimgravida.com', 25, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(7, 'Sonya', 'Cox', 'tellus@orci.org', 25, 6, 0, 0, 0),
(8, 'Aiko', 'Hodge', 'vestibulum.neque.sed@vel.edu', 25, 7, 6, 0, 0),
(9, 'Lillith', 'Bray', 'purus.Duis.elementum@necurnasuscipit.org', 25, 8, 7, 6, 0),
(10, 'Macey', 'Hayes', 'mi.pede@aliquetodioEtiam.net', 25, 9, 8, 7, 6);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

1. The default status is 25. (25,28,30,35,40) See this basically as a discount system, where the more people you refer and the more people they refer where you where the originating referer, you receive larger discounts.
2. If User A has at least 10 unique users he has referenced as refchid1 he gains status.
3. If User A has at least 10 uniuque users in refchid1 that each in turn has 10 unique users in refchid1 where User A is refchid2, he gains status.
4. User A has 10 unique users in rechid1 that each have 10 unique users in refchid1 where user A is rechid2 that in turn have 10 unique users in refchid1 where user A is refchid3.
5. etc.

As stated, the structure of testing is complex and I wish to do this without overloading the mysql server with millions of queries. The query should be an UPDATE query that will adjust the status of all matching users.

Does anyone have a solution of how I am going to accomplish this?

Comment: So thinking of this as a tree basically you mean for every 10 users referred in any level all user in higher levels gain 1 status point?

Comment: That is a correct assumption.
Explanation:
User A has 10 referels on refchid1, of those 10 referals on refchid1 each of them have User A on their refchid2 where they have refered 10 users each at refchid1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should have created a list of user, and a seperate table for references,

```
CREATE TABLE reference
(
    reference_id SERIAL,
    new_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    refered_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    reference_depth INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

and when you add a new user, if that user was refered by another user, add one row whit depth 1,

```
INSERT INTO reference SET
    new_user_id = $new_user_id, 
    refered_user_id =  $refered_user_id, 
    reference_depth = 1
```

then select all references linked to that user and add depth whit 1:

```
INSERT INTO reference (new_user_id, refered_user_id, reference_depth)
SELECT $new_user_id, refered_user_id, reference_depth +1
FROM reference WHERE new_user_id = $refered_user_id;
```

and then to calculate points

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    IF(reference_depth = 1, 10, 0) 
    + IF(reference_depth = 2, 3, 0) 
    + IF(reference_depth = 3, 2, 0)
    + IF(reference_depth > 3, 1, 0)
  )
FROM reference
WHERE new_user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back to you. Thanks.

Comment: The code that you gave is to build a Closure Table model. The calculate points part would not work as described, but if I use this model and set the SELECT SUM IF (reference_depth = 1,1,0) then I get a result of how many level1 referers there where, same for finding levels 2-4, which is exactly what I wanted. Have been reading up on Closure Tables by Bill Karwin and will be changing my project to use that model instead. Thanks for the advice and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really got how you calculated the points, but this query probably give you enough data to work with, play with it and rewrite it to an update query when you got the formula working.

```
SELECT
 parent.*,
 SUM(IF(parent.id = child.refchid1, 1, 0)) AS count_ref1,
 SUM(IF(parent.id = child.refchid2, 1, 0)) AS count_ref2,
 SUM(IF(parent.id = child.refchid3, 1, 0)) AS count_ref3,
 SUM(IF(parent.id = child.refchid4, 1, 0)) AS count_ref4,
 COUNT(child.id) as count_ref
FROM users AS parent 
LEFT JOIN users AS child 
    ON (  parent.id = child.refchid1 
       OR parent.id = child.refchid2 
       OR parent.id = child.refchid3 
       OR parent.id = child.refchid4)
GROUP BY parent.id
```

Comment: I had a similar query before. I populated the database with 40 000 entries carefully setting up the hierarchy so that a couple of users from 1 - 116 would have refered everyone else.

Using your query above, the mysql server is still attempting to give me a result as I write this. 5 Minutes into running it. It is taking way too long to return a result :)

Comment: I left the query you suggested running for 45 minutes now, still no result :P

Comment: What keys/index do you have on the table? What dose a describe of above query says, do it use the keys?

Comment: If you look at my original post, there is my table. ID is the only key/index. from your question I gather that you wish me to setup more keys/indexes for the refchid fields?

Comment: whitout indexes, mysql going to match all rows whit all rows and then filter them, if you add the 4 indexes for the 4 columns, mysql do the filtering before combining the rows, and that lowers the time alot. ALTER TABLE users ADD KEY(refchid1), ADD KEY(refchid2), ADD KEY(refchid3), ADD KEY(refchid4);

Comment: I have done that, still nothing, mysqld uses most of the CPU power to do the work and after about 5 minutes I just get tired of waiting. There has to be a better or easier way to implement this. It is not an existing database, so there is no worries about the data, I can restructure it if you have a better suggestion for how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) ? 
As you are updating the status directly on the table's rows and not generating it dynamically through a view (which I prefer) I think that triggering an insert action and then creating the proper "if" statements can be a good idea.

Otherwise I would recommend not using *status* and *refchid** columns but only one *refid* which refers to the "parent" id and then using a view to generate the *status* value (regarding recursivelly the refid).

Comment: Using both answers I received, I think there might be a way to do this. Would you suggest this would be the best way to update the status on an insert?
[code]CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON card_holders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE users, ( SELECT SUM(refchid1) AS total FROM card_holders WHERE refchid1=3) AS total
SET status = 
CASE
 WHEN status = "25" THEN status = "28" 
 WHEN status = "28" THEN status = "30"
 WHEN status = "30" THEN status = "35"
 WHEN status = "35" THEN status = "40"
WHERE total >= 10
END;[/code]